# Правильная сериализация

Tags: c#, json, сериализация

Познаю науку JSON в C#. Действую по статьям и мануалам. Поставил цель разбивать текст, на определенный JSON. Для того, чтобы редактировать новость на сайте не вглядываясь каждый раз в JSON. И так есть такой JSON:

```
{
  "feed": {
    "feedBoxes": [
      {
        "$type": "newsBox",
        "title": "Заголовок",
        "id": "top_news",
        "content": [
          {
            "$type": "Paragraph",
            "content": [
              {
                "$type": "Text",
                "value": "Первый абзац"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "$type": "Paragraph",
            "content": [
              {
                "$type": "Text",
                "value": "Первый абзац"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Подключил Newtonsoft.Json, начал серелизовать ,но в один момент упёрся в это:
Мой код класс для сереализации:

```
    public partial class FeedNews
    {
        [JsonProperty("feed")]
        public Feed Feed { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Feed
    {
        [JsonProperty("feedBox")]
        public List<FeedBox> FeedBoxes { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class FeedBox
    {
        [JsonProperty("$type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("content")]
        public List<FeedBoxContent> Content { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class FeedBoxContent
    {
        [JsonProperty("$type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("content")]
        public List<ContentContent> Content { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class ContentContent
    {
        [JsonProperty("$type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("value")]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Вот так начинаю разбивать текст:

```
    FeedNews feed = new FeedNews
    {
        Feed = new Feed
        {
            FeedBoxes = new List<FeedBox>
            {
            }
        }
    };
```

И вот на этом моменте всё получается:

```
{
  "feed": {
    "feedBoxes": []
  }
}
```

А дальше не понимаю как задать значения полей. Думал, что:

```
FeedNews feed = new FeedNews
{
    Feed = new Feed
    {
        FeedBoxes = new FeedBox<FeedBox>
        {
                    Title = "123",
                    Type = "123",
                    Id = "123",
                    Content = new FeedBoxContent
                    {
                        Type = "text",
                        Content = "content"
                    }
        }
    }
};
```

Помогите, объясните, как правильно вкладывть данный в такие запросы.

Comment: Статью на JSON? Мне кажется для статьи больше XML подойдет

Comment: Там новость в шапке формируется из JSON. Не мной так придумано. Т.е. единственное, что я могу, чтобы изменить новость в шапке - отредактировать JSON. Каждый раз его редактировать не очень удобно. Вот я и хочу сделать преобразовалку. Вводишь текст - получаешь JSON.

Comment: Посмотрел я на структуру ваших классов и имена свойств... [WCF Syndication](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/wcf-syndication), [How to](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-create-a-basic-rss-feed), [SyndicationFeed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed?view=netframework-4.7.2) - не? Всё уже придумано до нас.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По сути тут нечего сложного нету, главное понимать какой тип используется.
Давайте пройдемся по порядку:

- `"feed": {}` - это простой объект с названием `feed`.
- `"feedBoxes": []` - это массив объектов с названием `feedBoxes`.
- `"title": "Заголовок"` - свойство, название которого `title`, а значение `"Заголовок"`.
  Тут надо понимать также тип. Если это текст, то `string`, число - `int` и т.д.

Теперь давайте составим всю структуру с нуля:

1. Создадим для удобства базовый класс, я назову его `Root`, в нем сделаем свойство класса `Feed`, которое для удобства сразу инициализируем. Получаем что то вроде:

   ```
   class Root
   {
       public Feed Feed { get; set; } = new Feed();
   }
   ```
2. Далее сам класс `Feed`, он содержит в себе массив `feedBoxes`, для удобной работы пусть это будет свойство с типом `List<FeedBox>`, ну и также инициализируем сразу:

   ```
   class Feed
   {
       public List<FeedBox> FeedBoxes { get; set; } = new List<FeedBox>();
   }
   ```
3. Каждый элемент `FeedBox` содержит в себе ряд свойств и массив `content`. Для удобного заполнения мы создадим еще конструктор, который будет принимать необходимые нам значения:

   ```
   class FeedBox
   {
       public FeedBox(string type, string title, string id)
       {
           Type = type;
           Title = title;
           Id = id;
       }

       [JsonProperty("$type")] public string Type { get; set; }
       public string Title { get; set; }
       public string Id { get; set; }
       [JsonProperty("Content")]
       public List<ContentMain> Contents { get; set; } = new List<ContentMain>();
   }
   ```
4. Остается сам `Content` и его "основной класс. В нем у нас всего два свойства, ну и конструктор:

   ```
   class Content
   {
       public Content(string type, string value)
       {
           Type = type;
           Value = value;
       }

       [JsonProperty("$type")] public string Type { get; set; }
       public string Value { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   ну и

   ```
   class ContentMain
   {
       public ContentMain(string type)
       {
           Type = type;
       }

       [JsonProperty("$type")] public string Type { get; set; }
       [JsonProperty("Content")]
       public List<Content> Contents { get; set; } = new List<Content>();
   }
   ```
5. Ну что, структуру мы сделали, давайте заполним:

   ```
   var root = new Root();
   var feetBox = new FeedBox("newsBox", "Заголовок", "top_news");

   var firstContent = new ContentMain("Paragraph");
   firstContent.Contents.Add(new Content("Text", "Первый абзац"));
   feetBox.Contents.Add(firstContent);

   var secondContent = new ContentMain("Paragraph");
   secondContent.Contents.Add(new Content("Text", "Первый абзац"));
   feetBox.Contents.Add(secondContent);
   root.Feed.FeedBoxes.Add(feetBox);
   ```
6. Все, осталось сериализировать. Я добавлю пару настроек сериализации для того, что бы все значения были в нижнем регистре и JSON формировался не в одну строку:

   ```
   var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
   {
       ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
       Formatting = Formatting.Indented
   };

   var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root, serializerSettings);
   ```

Все, видим следующий результат:

```
{
  "feed": {
    "feedBoxes": [
      {
        "$type": "newsBox",
        "title": "Заголовок",
        "id": "top_news",
        "content": [
          {
            "$type": "Paragraph",
            "content": [
              {
                "$type": "Text",
                "value": "Первый абзац"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "$type": "Paragraph",
            "content": [
              {
                "$type": "Text",
                "value": "Первый абзац"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Как видите все очень легко, простая работа с классами.

Comment: Спасибо. Всё-таки, собрался с силами ещё раз перечитал "как рисовать сову", опираясь на эти подсказки - очень помогло. Спасибо. Всё получилось.

Answer (score 2):

Ваша ошибка в том, что вы пытаетесь заполнить поля FeedBoxes и Content объектами, а нужно списками объектов.

я бы посоветовал подумать над структурой, ведь она кажется схожей для многих объектов.
Но можно и так:

```
FeedNews feed = new FeedNews
{
    Feed = new Feed
    {
        FeedBoxes = new List<FeedBox>
        {
            new FeedBox
            {
                Title = "123",
                Type = "123",
                Id = "123",
                Content = new List<FeedBoxContent>
                {
                    new FeedBoxContent
                    {
                        Type = "Paragraph",
                        Content = new List<ContentContent>
                        {
                            new ContentContent
                            { 
                                Type = "Text", 
                                Value = "Первый абзац" 
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new FeedBoxContent
                    {
                        Type = "Paragraph",
                        Content = new List<ContentContent>
                        {
                            new ContentContent
                            { 
                                Type = "Text", 
                                Value = "Первый абзац" 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } 
            }        
        } 
    }
};
```